# How to launch another app from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I am working on a map application in my iPhone app.

I have a button `go`.

When the user clicks this button in this method I want to check if user has installed the `waze` application on his iphone. If yes then navigate to waze application otherwise open iPhone's default map app.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to do this way :

```
NSString *wazeAppURL = @"waze://";
NSString *mapsAppURL = @"maps://";

BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wazeAppURL]];

NSString *url = canOpenURL ? wazeAppURL : mapsAppURL;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Here, `canOpenURL` allows you to test if the Waze app is installed on your iPhone. if iPhone can open the url `waze://` it means you already have the app and it will launch it. Otherwise it will launch the default Maps app. Safari won't be called.

Comment: hi if we open URL the control will go to safari and where i will get URL the app-store URL  or any thing else.my application point is from my app the user can navigate through waze while click on the button if waze application is installed in users phone other wise the default app.how can i check the waze app is installed in user's iPhone.can you please elaborate all these things.

Comment: @bs7 How can we get list of all routing app present in iphone, like In my phone I have google map, apple map & waze. How can I get that ?

Comment: Is there a way to get response when the external app is closed? Something like `onActivityResult` on Android?

Answer (score 5):

To open an app you need to call

```
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                       canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]];
if ( canOpenUrl ) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                       openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

To find all the url, go to this page: http://handleopenurl.com/

For waze in particular, http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/waze

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on iOS you can also navigate to Google Maps -- and pass along the query  string or geopoint. Here's one example of navigating to a specific geopoint:

```
if (self.mapView.userLocation.location) {
    NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%f,%f", self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString]];
    }
}
```

Just a suggestion to enhance the user experience.