# Launching a different app to open file on server

Tags: ios, objective-c

The [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) say that `UIDocumentInteractionController` "provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system".  Is there a similar setup for viewing files on a server?  I tried just sending the link to the file as the `NSURL` for `interactionControllerWithURL:`, but that didn't work.  I guess the alternative would be to download the file, then open it once it has downloaded, then delete the file.  That seems like a lot of extra coding work though, if there is an easier way that's already available.

---

Edit: I already know the name of the file I want to view/download, so I'm not really looking for the "file list" aspect of `UIDocumentInteractionController`.  On the server, there are many Google Earth .kml files.  The user isn't going to directly select which file to open from a list - I select the file to open programmatically based on actions taken by the user previously in the session.

As I understand it, `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` will show a popover something like "Would you like to open the file 'myFile.kml' in Google Earth?".  If the user selects 'Yes', the UIDocumentInteractionController launches Google Earth and opens myFile.kml.  So I guess I'm not really looking for a file list viewer, just a way to trigger an "Open With" kinda functionality, where the file I'm opening exists on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  I don't need to use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` at all for what I'm looking for.  I can simply

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgoogleearth://www.mysite.com/myfile.kml"];

BOOL canOpen = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
if (canOpen)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"Open failed. Make sure Google Earth is installed and the URL is correct.");
}
```

This will launch Google Earth with my file just like I'm looking for.

FYI, I got the scheme for Google Earth from [elpsk's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987914/how-to-launch-another-app-from-an-iphone-app).  It looks like a pretty comprehensive list of a lot of file types and the apps that open them.  Just replace the `comgoogleearth` in my URL with the scheme for whatever app you are trying to open a file with.

Answer (score 1):

UIDocumentInteraction controller can't be used to view list of files present on server.
UIDocument interaction controller takes local file present in source application and shows list of applications that can open that file.Once use clicks on file then it is transferred to target app.

If you want to get file from server then you can use NSURLConnection class to download file form server and store it on device.

Comment: Hm, actually I'm not trying to show a list of files the user can choose, I just need to open a file that I specify with another app.  I realized that was not clear in my OP, so I've updated it.  Maybe `UIDocumentInteractionController` is not what I'm looking for after all.