# Open default application with nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am quite surprised I have yet to find an answer to this on the internet.

How do I open a native/default app from my nativescript app?

In this instance I want to open a map application with a location parameter (not sure if it will be a string, coordinates, etc).

Comment: What do you mean by "default" ? See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005809/4936697

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **utils**

```
var utilsModule = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");

utilsModule.openUrl("<< for example: maps short link>>");
```

In fact it will try to open map link with browser. But android && ios will ask to you “do you want to open it via Maps?” at first.

There may be some plugins for opening via maps directly without any question but I think this way is better (you dont need to install a plugin)

For more info about utils, see [that](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils)

Comment: I forgot to say (for your last sentences) : to use location parameter ; so to create link manually with user’s entry (latitude-longitude) ,  http://www.google.com/maps/places/“add latitude and longitude data here that users’ wanted” . For example: https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/51.9514091,4.5555206

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted it to. In fact, in testing it, it opened Google maps quite seamlessly. If anyone stumbles upon this, [here is the maps resource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) I found to do queries to open the map to specific location